# Growth of residues of $1/\zeta(s)$: conjectures?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

Let $\rho$ range over the non-trivial zeroes of the Riemann zeta function. Let
$$M(T) = \max_{|\Im \rho|\leq T} \left|\mathrm{Res}_{s=\rho} \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\right| = 
\max_{|\Im \rho|\leq T} \frac{1}{|\zeta'(\rho)|}.$$
Are there any conjectures, or even just vague, reasonable guesses, as to what the growth of $M(T)$ should be?

Here's a picture of $1/|\zeta'(\rho)|$ against $(\log \Im \rho)^2$ for the first 50000 zeros with $\Im \rho>0$. The green line is of slope $1/3$, i.e., it corresponds to a bound of $(\log T)^2/3$.

[image]

Addendum (following @Lucia's comment): here is a plot of $1/|\zeta'(\rho)|$ against $(\Im \rho)^{1/3}$ for the first $50000$ zeros. The green line is of slope $6/5$, that is, it corresponds to a bound $\frac{6}{5} T^{1/3}$.

[image]

Residues courtesy of D. Platt.

Comment: Residue of $f$ equals $1/f'$ only when the root of $f$ is simple, is this known for Zeta?

Comment: It's not known but believed for $\zeta$.

Comment: The usual guess is that pair correlation predicts that up to height $T$ there may be a pair of zeros that are within $T^{-1/3 +o(1)}$ of each other.   This then suggests that$1/\zeta'(\rho)$ maybe grows like $T^{1/3 +o(1)}$.  This is an unpublished conjecture of Gonek.  For related work, see for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.09368.pdf and references therein.

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394323/what-is-the-best-known-upper-bound-for-frac1-zeta-rho-assuming-the-szc

Comment: @HAHelfgott then your second equality is only conjectural

Comment: Sure. But the conjecture I am asking for is much more conjectural :P. More seriously, if you are checking $\zeta'(\rho)$ up to a certain height, you are also checking that all the zeros are simple.

Comment: @Lucia Out of curiosity - is there a conjecture or guess on what the constant $$C=\lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{0<\Im \rho \leq T} 1/|\zeta'(\rho)|}{T (\log T)^{1/4}}$$ should be? It seems to be roughly around $0.15$.

Comment: (It also seems to provide an upper bound on the quantity whose limit we are taken, but obviously I can't be sure.)

Comment: @HAHelfgott : Hughes, Keating and O'Connell used the random matrix theory analogy to conjecture that constant, and constants for similar moments (link: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1799857). See also, https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3341497.

Comment: @AnuragSahay Thanks. That's not a very pretty-looking constant - I suppose there is no chance than one might be able to get something a little nicer for this sum (corresponding to $k=-1/2$ there)?

Comment: To be precise: the constant there is $\exp\left(3 \zeta'(-1)+\frac{\log 2}{12}+ \frac{\log \pi}{2}\right) a\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$, where $a(k)$ is given as an infinite product of series. I'm skimming through references given, and they seem to imply that $a(k)$ is a factor that was known from well before H-K-O'C. What would be a good reference? If there were a nicer expression for $a(-1/2)$, it surely would be somewhere. (Of course one can compute $a(k)$ quickly from the infinite product using standard tricks to accelerate convergence.)

Comment: The $a(k)$ there is the same as the one in the Keating-Snaith conjectures for the usual continuous moments of zeta (although I do not think the KS conjectures are expected to hold when $k$ is as low as $-1/2$), so probably the right place to look is their paper, or the work of Conrey-Ghosh and Conrey-Gonek. I don't know any nice expression for $a(-1/2)$ off the top of my head.

Comment: The impression I was getting from the slides in https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/seminar/20040205163017301-148335.pdf (Hughes) is that the factor $a(k)$ was known (to the extent that part of a conjectural expression can be "known") and what was new was the other factor.

Comment: Yes, I think your impression is correct. $a(k)$ is just the Euler product factor that one gets from the diagonal terms, as I understand it; the so-called geometric factor $g(k)$ in the KS conjectures comes from the fact that off-diagonals start contributing (which is why it was hard to conjecture the right value of say, $g(5)$ using the work of Conrey et al). But the pre-KS work was quite focused on the integer $k$ case, I don't know a simpler expression for half-integers. You could email Brian Conrey -- I'm sure he would know a simpler expression if it's in the literature.

Comment: $a(k)$ is already there in Conrey-Ghosh, Mean Values of the Riemann Zeta Function (1984). Conrey points out that $a_k = a_{1-k}$ is proved in Conrey-Ghosh, Mean Values of the Riemann Zeta Function, III (1992), but that doesn't seem to help here.

Comment: Conrey points out that $a(k)$ appears already in a 1928 paper by Titchmarsh. (I think that is for $k$ an integer, but the generalization is natural.) See Titchmarsh, Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function, section 7.19.

Comment: Just to be clear - the constant given above, $\exp\left(3\zeta′(−1)+\frac{\log 2}{12}+\frac{\log \pi}{2}\right) a(−1/2)$, is the conjectured limit for $$\frac{\sum_{0<\Im \rho\leq T} \frac{1}{|\zeta'(\rho)|}}{\frac{T}{2 \pi} \left(\log \frac{T}{2\pi}\right)^{1/4}}.$$

Comment: A few lines in Sagemath give me (in a couple of seconds) that $a(-1/2) = 0.918488401889574770178443471101777130994726642337187508616479134752822306436742044340260 \pm 4\cdot 10^{-88},$ and so $\sum_{0<\Im \rho\leq T} \frac{1}{|\zeta'(\rho)|}$ should asymptote to $c T (\log T)^{1/4}$, where the constant $c$ equals $0.1671206468489329995931538177154026590678081925141475125414745036183458075814364849683264 \pm 9\cdot 10^{-89}$.

Comment: (The procedure for computing Euler products to high precision quickly is standard.)