# Order of growth of $\left|\frac{1}{\zeta’(\rho)}\right|$ as $\Im(\rho)\rightarrow\infty$?

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $\zeta$ denote the Riemann zeta function, and let $\rho\in\mathbb{C}$ be a variable that takes its values among the zeros of the zeta function, so that $\zeta(\rho)=0$, and write $\rho=\sigma+it$. What is the best known upper bound for the order of growth of
$\left|\frac{1}{\zeta’(\rho)}\right|$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$? I am interested in answers both, assuming and without assuming the Riemann hypothesis. Can you please supply a reference? I am thinking that no upperbound is known since Spira [1] proves that the zeros of $\zeta’$ on the critical line, if they exist, necessarily coincide with zeros of $\zeta$. But the result by Spira is old.

[1] Spira, R., On the Riemann zeta function, Journal of the London Mathematical Society, 44 (1969), 325-328

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/411943/growth-of-residues-of-1-zetas-conjectures

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394323/what-is-the-best-known-upper-bound-for-frac1-zeta-rho-assuming-the-szc

Comment: @Terry Tao Thanks, I had not seen the first post you noted. Before I saw it, I had already started to compute something like the graphs in that question, but to a greater number of zeros. If you plot the values of $1/|\zeta'(1/2+it)|$ in small increments of t instead of just for the residues of $1/\zeta(s)$ you see the same asymptote more clearly.